# objc_release crash with no origin in my code

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, crash

I'm getting this strange crash with no indication from where it's going. I am not able to reproduce this on my devices. Any idea what could be wrong and where to look for the problem?

It looks it happens in autorelease pool cleaning in main loop, however I am not affecting it in my app - I am using ARC. The `AppDelegate.swift` line 21 is just declaration of `AppDelagate` class.

I am not able to reproduce this problem on any of my devices (I have about 8 of them), but this crash happens to about 10% of users of the new version, so that it is pretty frequent. I tried some build as the AppStore one.

[image]
Thanks,
Jindrich

Comment: You have memory leaks?  How do you know that?

Comment: Even though you are using ARC, some legacy (Foundation) objects might still use the autorelease pool. The error indicates access to a dangling (e.g. already deleted) pointer. You should enable the "Address Sanitizer" (in the diagnostics section of the scheme) to find out more.

Comment: Address sanitiser don't report anything.